# Android WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

Im trying to make an app in which you can see youtube videos,
in my layout I have an textbox an imagebutton and a webview for that.

Now I want android to display a toast when the url in the webview changes,
and if it is possible only the urls where "watch?" is in it.

until now I tried this stuff with "shouldOverrideUrlLoading",
the purpose of this is to keep the user on the youtube website and
display a toast when the user clicked a video, here is the code:

```java
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        public void search() {
        surl = MainAct.ytresurl + MainAct.query;
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        MainAct.wv.loadUrl(MainAct.surl);
        WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
                if (!url.startsWith("http://m.youtube.com/")) {
                    MainAct.wv.loadUrl(surl);
                    return true;
                } else if (url.startsWith("http://m.youtube.com/watch?")) {
                    MainAct.vidurl = url;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL:" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    MainAct.wv.loadUrl(surl);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        MainAct.wv.setWebViewClient(wvc/*new Callback()*/);
    }
```

the surl is the url with the query (the space to %20 convert is not implented yet)
the MainAct.vidurl is the url of the video the user is gonna watch.

But when im testing my code, the toast for watching a video dont show up, any suggestions?

Thank you,
Wout